# empty fields are taken into database..!

Tags: php, database

Here is the code that I have tried for validation of data entered in the fields. Even though I have specified that empty fields should not be entered, on submit the data is getting entered into the database..!!

```
<?php
require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => false);
if ((isset($_POST['fname']) || isset($_POST['lname']) || isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['password']) || isset($_POST['mobile']) !== ''){
    // receiving the post params
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $password, $mobile);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["uid"] = $user["id"];
        $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
        $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (fname, lname, email, password or mobile) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: may i know where you checked empty fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `isset` function only checks that a variable is set. An inverted `empty` will check that a variable is set and not empty. So try:

```
if (!empty($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['mobile'])){
```

Links:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Also note that `0` is considered empty.

Comment: thanks a lot sir...for correcting my silliest of mistake...!!

Comment: but sir plz may i know how to validate email in backend..!! for same question..!!?

Comment: What do you consider a valid email? It can receive email; just that it has an `@`; that the user actually owns the address provided? You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php; all depends on your criteria of `valid`..

Comment: yes..sir but wer can i include that regular expression in my code..?

Comment: You could do it in your big `if` or before that as its own `if`. Depends on the behavior you want. Also I didn't give you a regex; did you want a regex? Maybe: https://regex101.com/r/dY4yX3/1?